# How can you break text that is really long?

Tags: html, css, text, breakpoints, word-wrap

I am not quite sure how to do this.

I'm trying to break up text that is too long. (E.g. hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii)

I've tried using `word-wrap: break-word;` but this isn't doing anything.

Comment: Thanks, sub-pixel smoothing. Now those `i`s are green between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word-break` was now renamed to `overflow-wrap` as you can [read in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap0). But browsers should accept the `word-break` rule.

You can also try to play around with text-overflow a litte bit. PPK wrote about it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) and you can find more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Text-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `-webkit-hyphens` css3 property. There is support for some other vendor prefixes as well.

http://drublic.de/blog/css3-auto-hyphenation-for-text-elements/